# Continuously Invertible?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I came through this term [in a book](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=cs8oDwAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PR16&dq=fundamentals%20of%20nonparametric%20bayesian%20inference&ots=SdywrElnyV&sig=imNmVo62etq_8v8J8RnpuB0qKgM#v=onepage&q=fundamentals%20of%20nonparametric%20bayesian%20inference&f=false) as the following picture shows:
[image]

From the logic of it, it seems to me that what it means that the function is invertible and **its inverse** is continuous, but I couldn't find any textbook definition for this concept. The closest thing I found was here:
[image]

Which is in line with what I think. But wanted to ask and make sure. Can somebody please tell me where to find this definition. Am I looking at the wrong places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's slightly different to having a continuous inverse. Here, the inverse might not exist as a function with a well-defined output, but the operation of pre-image acts as a continuous inverse.

Let's first see what happens when $f$ *is* invertible, with inverse $g$, and suppose that $g$ is continuous. If $f:X\to Y$, then $g$ continuous and $g=f^{-1}$ means that $g:Y\to X$ and for every open neighbourhood $U$ of $x\in X$, the preimage (here, the inverse) $g^{-1}(U)$ is open in $Y$. Since $g^{-1}=f$, this means that for every open neighbourhood $U$ of $x\in X$, we have $f(x)\in f(U)$ and $f(U)$ is open, i.e. $V=f(U)$ is an open neighbourhood of $f(x)$ and certainly $f^{-1}(V)=f^{-1}f(U)=U\subseteq U$, so this satisfies your given definition.

What happens if $f$ is not invertible? We can attempt to have all of the above, with $V=f(U)$, but notice that since $f$ is not bijective, $f^{-1}(V)=f^{-1}f(U)\supseteq U$, rather than $\subseteq U$, so a general function $f$ sadly will not satisfy this condition. It is then interesting when $f$ satisfies that condition, as it means that the preimage $f^{-1}$ acts *like* a continuous function, in the above sense, on some open subset of $U$ for any neighbourhood $U$, in that it can associate some open subset of $U$ with an open neighbourhood of $f(x)$.

Comment: Thanks. From your answer I am still not following if continuously invertible is your first case or your second case. Also are you aware of a textbook/reference that contains this definition/idea?

Comment: The whole time I was talking about continuously invertible as per the definition you provided. The first case was an examination of the motivation for the definition; I showed that a function with a continuous inverse is “continuously invertible”, but I also explained in the second paragraph why the definition is meaningful even if the function itself is not strictly invertible @Cupitor

Comment: @Cupitor I cannot authoritatively say that the definition you found is the same as the definition the authors of that book intended, but I can say that it would make sense to refer to this as continuously invertible rather than having a continuous inverse since the condition of having an inverse is stronger than needed here.

Comment: Thanks so much! That was very helpful.